# What does this line of Rails 3 Do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  def self.source_root
    File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'templates')
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you can call Class.source_root on a class and it will return it's path name with 'templates' appended on the end. So say you had

```
Class User
  def self.source_root
    File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'templates')
  end
end
```

In the directory application/model/

If you call

```
User.source_root
```

It returns

```
"application/model/templates"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use irb to see what it does. You can debug variables and test what they do.

It's a class method so you can create a class in irb and test what it does.

Run irb like so :-

irb(main):001:0> def self.source_root

irb(main):002:1>       File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), 'templates')

irb(main):003:1>     end
=> nil

irb(main):004:0> class Foo

irb(main):005:1>   def self.source_root

irb(main):006:2>         File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), 'templates')

irb(main):007:2>       end

irb(main):008:1>   end

=> nil

irb(main):009:0> Foo.source_root

=> "./templates"

irb(main):010:0>

irb(main):010:0> **FILE**

=> "(irb)"

irb(main):011:0> File.dirname(**FILE**)

=> "."